# Django app on heroku, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spread'

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment, modulenotfounderror

I am strugling with running my app on heroku. Everything works fine on a local machine.  Ive deployed a django app to heroku with no issues (`git push heroku master` is working properly) however whenever I am trying to `heroku open` heroku logs are pointing out an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spread'`

I've researched most of the stackoverflow related questions and google articules and tutorials but with no sucess. I hope this is just some simple issue that I cant figure out. Any help will be much appriciated. Thanks

**heroku logs --tail** error presented at the bottom

```
2020-12-18T12:55:21.766372+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-12-18T12:55:29.108110+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn spread.wsgi`
2020-12-18T12:55:32.531785+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-12-18 12:55:32 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2020-12-18T12:55:32.532683+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-12-18 12:55:32 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:48488 (4)
2020-12-18T12:55:32.532859+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-12-18 12:55:32 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2020-12-18T12:55:32.542317+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-12-18 12:55:32 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2020-12-18T12:55:32.562471+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-12-18 12:55:32 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2020-12-18T12:55:32.562473+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-12-18T12:55:32.562473+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2020-12-18T12:55:32.562474+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2020-12-18T12:55:32.562475+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
2020-12-18T12:55:32.562475+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2020-12-18T12:55:32.562475+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
2020-12-18T12:55:32.562476+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2020-12-18T12:55:32.562477+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2020-12-18T12:55:32.562477+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2020-12-18T12:55:32.562477+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2020-12-18T12:55:32.562478+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-12-18T12:55:32.562478+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2020-12-18T12:55:32.562479+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-12-18T12:55:32.562479+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2020-12-18T12:55:32.562479+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2020-12-18T12:55:32.562480+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2020-12-18T12:55:32.562480+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-12-18T12:55:32.562481+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
2020-12-18T12:55:32.562481+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
2020-12-18T12:55:32.562482+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-12-18T12:55:32.562482+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2020-12-18T12:55:32.562483+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
2020-12-18T12:55:32.562483+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
2020-12-18T12:55:32.562483+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-12-18T12:55:32.562484+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spread'
2020-12-18T12:55:32.562704+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-12-18 12:55:32 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2020-12-18T12:55:32.584211+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-12-18 12:55:32 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
2020-12-18T12:55:32.593502+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-12-18 12:55:32 +0000] [11] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2020-12-18T12:55:32.593504+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-12-18T12:55:32.593504+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2020-12-18T12:55:32.593505+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2020-12-18T12:55:32.593505+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
2020-12-18T12:55:32.593506+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2020-12-18T12:55:32.593506+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
2020-12-18T12:55:32.593506+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2020-12-18T12:55:32.593507+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2020-12-18T12:55:32.593508+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2020-12-18T12:55:32.593508+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2020-12-18T12:55:32.593508+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-12-18T12:55:32.593509+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2020-12-18T12:55:32.593509+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-12-18T12:55:32.593510+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2020-12-18T12:55:32.593510+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2020-12-18T12:55:32.593510+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2020-12-18T12:55:32.593511+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-12-18T12:55:32.593511+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
2020-12-18T12:55:32.593512+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
2020-12-18T12:55:32.593512+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-12-18T12:55:32.593513+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2020-12-18T12:55:32.593513+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
2020-12-18T12:55:32.593513+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
2020-12-18T12:55:32.593514+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-12-18T12:55:32.593514+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spread'
2020-12-18T12:55:32.595098+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-12-18 12:55:32 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
2020-12-18T12:55:32.704864+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-12-18 12:55:32 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2020-12-18T12:55:32.705193+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-12-18 12:55:32 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2020-12-18T12:55:32.794501+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2020-12-18T12:55:32.945834+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

**project structure**:

```
spread-polska/
├── Include (ignored)
├── Lib (ignored)
├── Include (ignored)
├── media_cdn (ignored)
├── Scripts (ignored)
├── src
│   ├── idea (ignored)
│   ├── linksadded (includes models)
│   ├── spread
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── storage_backends.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── wsgi.py
│   ├── static
│   ├── staticfiles
│   ├── templates
│   ├── users (includes models)
│   ├── db.sqlite3 (ignored)
│   ├── manage.py
├── static_cdn
├── .gitignore
├── Procfile
├── requirements.txt
└── runtime.txt
```

**wsgi.py**

```
import os
import sys

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

path = u"/klimu/Dev/spread-polska/src"

if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, path)

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "spread.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**Procfile**

```
web: gunicorn spread.wsgi
```

**runtime.txt**

```
python-3.7.4
```

**requirements.txt**

```
boto3==1.16.30
botocore==1.19.30
chardet==3.0.4
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==2.2.17
django-bootstrap-pagination==1.7.1
django-crispy-forms==1.9.2
django-heroku==0.3.1
django-storages==1.10.1
djangorestframework==3.10.3
gunicorn==20.0.4
jmespath==0.10.0
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
Pillow==7.0.0
psycopg2==2.8.6
psycopg2-binary==2.8.6
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2019.2
requests==2.22.0
s3transfer==0.3.3
six==1.15.0
sqlparse==0.4.1
stripe==2.48.0
urllib3==1.25.6
whitenoise==5.2.0
```

**settings.py** for reference I am using S3 to serve my static and media files

```
import stripe
import os
import django_heroku

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

stripe.api_key = os.environ.get('stripe_api_key')

SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get("DJANGO_SECRET_KEY_PROD")

DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['www.spread-demo.herokuapp.com',]

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'crispy_forms',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'bootstrap_pagination',
    'storages',
    'rest_framework',

    #custom apps
    'linksadded',
    'users',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'spread.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'spread.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'

DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_BACKEND = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_BACKEND,
    'users.authentication_backends.EmailBackend',
)

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Warsaw'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_cdn")
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get("AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME")
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = os.environ.get("AWS_S3_REGION_NAME")

AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}

AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'spread.storage_backends.MediaStorage'
AWS_LOCATION = 'static'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "media_cdn")

VALID_IMAGE_EXTENSIONS = [
    "jpg",
    "jpeg",
    "png",
    "gif",
    "webp",
]

AUCTION_PER_PAGE = 2

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

SHORTCODE_MAX = 15
SHORTCODE_MIN = 6

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get("EMAIL_HOST_USER")
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get("EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD")

# using heroku db
import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config()
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
# DATABASES['default']['CONN_MAX_AGE'] = 500

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION:
I had to move the content of the src folder to the root folder and this has fixed the issue